# В чём польза от QSequentialIterable и QAssociativeIterable?

Tags: c++, qt5

Начиная с версии 5.2, Qt обзавёлся двумя классами, позволяющими производить перебор элементов контейнеров с вариативным типом данных. `QSequentialIterable` для `QList` (и аналогичных) и `QAssociativeIterable` для `QHash` и `QMap`.

Из представленного в справке к ним описания никак не могу понять, а зачем они вообще нужны, если те же `QVariantList` или `QVariantMap` прекрасно перебираются через обычный `foreach` или собственные итераторы. Точно также в цикле получаем `QVariant`, который опять же надо преобразовывать к исходному типу, содержащемуся в контейнере. В чём тогда их отличие и в чём выигрыш от использования новых `Iterable`?

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь](https://dps-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/publication/publication/171/StephenKellyType-ErasedContainerIteration.pdf) линка на документ, автор которого - Стивен Келли, разработчик Grantlee. Этот парень должен смыслить в Qt ))) Учитывая, что сабж этого вопроса - вроде как его детище.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы сделать перевод, может быть краткий, с тем, чтобы ответ и аргументация в нём были удобоваримы подавляющему большинству пользователей сайта, предпочитающих информацию на русском языке? Спасибо.